# Offsetting the index in pandas dataframe (keep content intact)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have 2 dataframes, one has data for period X and the other has the data for period X-1 (could be day or month).

**Data example:**

```
DF1 (time X):

                Item 1       Item 2
2018-01-02       0.431        0.656
2018-01-03       0.439        0.668
2018-01-04       0.447        0.680
2018-01-05       0.455        0.692
2018-01-08       0.479        0.729
2018-01-09       0.487        0.741
2018-01-10       0.495        0.753

DF1 (time X-1):

                Item 1       Item 2
2018-01-02       0.429        0.651
2018-01-03       0.431        0.656
2018-01-04       0.439        0.668
2018-01-05       0.447        0.680
2018-01-08       0.455        0.692
2018-01-09       0.479        0.729
2018-01-10       0.487        0.741
```

I want my resuling dataframe to be:

```
X Final:
                Item 1       Item 2
2018-01-01       0.429        0.651
2018-01-02       0.431        0.656
2018-01-03       0.439        0.668
2018-01-04       0.447        0.680
2018-01-05       0.455        0.692
2018-01-08       0.479        0.729
2018-01-09       0.487        0.741
2018-01-10       0.495        0.753
```

**What I already tried:** I was initially trying to merge the last column of X array with x-1 array, and offset the index, but in doing that, I also offset the data, which is not what I want:

```
df_xfinal = df_x1.iloc[:]
df_xlastrow = df_x.iloc[-1:]
df_xfinal = df_xfinal.append(df_xlastrow)
df_xfinal = df_xfinal.shift(periods=-1, axis=0)
```

**Question:** Can this be done in a straightforward way, without having through loop across all the array items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
# Make sure the indices are datetimes (if they aren't already)
DF1.index = pd.to_datetime(DF1.index)
DF2.index = pd.to_datetime(DF2.index)

# subtract a day from the index of df2
DF2.index = DF2.index - pd.Timedelta('1d')

# concatenate the two dataframes, sort by index, and drop duplicates
final_df = pd.concat([DF1, DF2]).sort_index().drop_duplicates()
```

Which returns:

```
>>> final_df
            Item 1  Item 2
2018-01-01   0.429   0.651
2018-01-02   0.431   0.656
2018-01-03   0.439   0.668
2018-01-04   0.447   0.680
2018-01-05   0.455   0.692
2018-01-08   0.479   0.729
2018-01-09   0.487   0.741
2018-01-10   0.495   0.753
```

Comment: Sport on, many thanks. One question, how can I remove the timestamp (hours, minutes...) from the index values after using the pd.to_datetime?

Comment: You're welcome! you can do this to remove the time from the datetimeindex:  `df.index = df.index.date`